# Enter data in an Android popup

Tags: android, popup, android-edittext

I want the user to enter a string into an EditText into a popup. I have taken a look in Android Developers [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) .

But this kind of popup is not explained. How can I make it?

Comment: They do, the last part in that page deals with "creating a custom dialog", which is what you want.

Comment: I guess you're right, I over-read and thought that was a normal popup, not a customizable. I'll try to do it, but do you know of any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the same page you linked to, [check out how they say to create a custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).

Create an XML layout for the dialog that has an EditText.  Then show it:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom dialog by extending `Dialog`. Your custom dialog class will have an `onCreate()` callback, in which you can call `setContentView` to whatever view you want, just like with an `Activity`.

Simply create a view to look however you'd like and use that one. Then, when you want to use your dialog, simply get an instance, like `Dialog myDialog = new MyCustomDialog(getParent(), R.style.some_style);` and then `myDialog.show();`